# Trying to add one part of a List to another using a Spinbox and RadioButtons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've recently been working on something where you have a list on names and only when a certain radiobutton has been clicked and a button is pressed does it happen.

```
from tkinter import *
main_window = Tk()
v = IntVar()
def preorder():
    pass
preorder_button = Radiobutton(main_window, text = "PreOrder", indicatoron = 0,
              width = 10,
              padx = 20, 
              variable=v, 
              command=preorder,
              value=1)

# Making a Spin wheel
wheel = Spinbox(main_window, from_=1, to=2, width = 3, bd=0, font = (24))

# Shopping cart list
shopping_cart = Text(main_window, width = 30, height = 10, borderwidth = 2, relief = 'groove')

# Making an 'Add To Cart' Button
var = 0
InvoiceList = []
A_List = ['Hello', 'Goodbye']
def AddToCart():
    global var, InvoiceList
    spinInt = int(wheel.get())
    if v == 1:
        InvoiceList.append(str(A_List[int(wheel.get()) - 1]))

    print(InvoiceList)
    shopping_cart.insert(END, InvoiceList[var] + '\n')
    var = var + 1

AddCartButton = Button(main_window, text="Add To Cart", width=10, padx=20, command=AddToCart).grid(row=8, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=SW)

preorder_button.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
wheel.grid(row = 3, column = 3, rowspan = 2)
shopping_cart.grid(row = 6, column = 1, columnspan = 4)
main_window.mainloop()
```

The problem is though that no matter what I do, i always get an error saying that theres nothing inside the Invoice String, so I'm guessing that it's a problem with how the codes adding a part from the first list to the second list but I have no idea whats wrong with it.

Heres the error i get:

```
    []
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jackb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/Users/jackb/Documents/UNI/IFB104/Assignment 2/online_shopping_app.py", line 332, in AddToCart
    shopping_cart.insert(END, InvoiceList[var] + '\n')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What this code is supposed to do is while the radiobutton is checked and you press the button, it copies one part of the list according to what the spinbox is set to to another for future use and then displays the added item in the text box for the user to see

Comment: Your error message is truncated and your code isn't runnable. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Ok thanks, i fixed it just now

Comment: Ok, the code runs, but I don't understand what the code is supposed to *do*. You access increasing indices in `InvoiceList` (because `var = var + 1`), but you only *add* values to `InvoiceList` if the "preorder" radiobutton is checked. One press of the button while "preorder" isn't checked will throw that IndexError.

Comment: What this code is supposed to do is while the radiobutton is checked and you press the button, it copies one part of the list according to what the spinbox is set to to another for future use and then displays the added item in the text box for the user to see

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after a bit. The problem was that the If statement is checking `v` when it should be checking `v.get()` instead since `v` by itself just gives back `IntVar()`. You can see this here when you do `print(v)` vs `print(v.get())` since `v` by itself outputs `PY_VAR0` but `v.get()` outputs `1`